# Matching repeated character on index (0,1) and also on index (1,2)

Tags: ruby, regex

I've got a string

> 698636235|2004-02-19||UN|
>
> 713220614|2009-10-07|||

This is part of a pipe-separated file <sub>(I know....)</sub> that I'm trying to load into MySQL.

I'm trying to use regex to fill empty field values with `\N` so that MySQL will insert `null`. However this is a problem when there are multiple fields that are null values.

My current regex is `/\|\|/` which matches one instance of double pipe. This regex will match once at index (0,1).

Is it possible for regex to match `|||` twice? Once at index (0,1) and once at index (1,2)?

If no, I'll just write a proper looping function.

Comment: Can't you use CSV.read with col_sep | and then replace empty fields with \n ?

Comment: Why not `split` the line by `|`, replace empty elements and `join` again?

Comment: It's not only consecutive pipe characters (`foo||bar`), you also have to deal with single leading (`|foo|bar`) and trailing (`foo|bar|`) pipe characters, don't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest using look-arounds:

```
(?<=^|\||\n)(?=\||$|\n)
```

It finds the zero-width space between to vertical bars, **or** between a vertical bar and start/end of the line/text (=empty field).

The first part, the positive look-behind `(?<=` checks that the position we are interested in is preceded by start of text `^`, a vertical bar `|` or a new line `\n`.

The second part, the positive look-ahead `(?=`, ensures it's followed by vertical bar, new line or end of text `$`.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vJ2zL8/3).

**Edit**

As per comment, added support for empty field at start of line. (Had to check, but from what I can see ruby supports look-behinds. Original if someone needs it in JS: `\|(?=\||$|\n)`)

Comment: What about a leading bar / empty first field, e.g. `|2009-10-07`?

Comment: That looks good, maybe you should add some explanation, the regex has become quite large ;-)

Comment: In Ruby, `^` and `$` always match at line boundaries, so the `\n` branch is redundant.  It's not necessarily correct, either; how do you know the text doesn't use `\r\n` lie separators?

Comment: @AlanMoore That's normally handled by the regex internals.

Comment: I checked, and it seems Ruby converts newlines to just `\n` when reading in text (unless you specify otherwise).  But the effect is the same: it's safe to use `\n` in the regex.  So you're right about that, but it's still redundant.